# Mysql same column data filtering

Tags: php, mysql

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUi20.png)
My table is like this. When I choose the list I want to create, women and Red are selected, when asked to list IN command, male and red values ​​are also displayed. How can I create the query?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product_attribute 
 WHERE attribute_values IN ('Kadın','Kırmızı')   
 GROUP 
    BY product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product_id
FROM product_attribute 
WHERE attribute_values IN ('Kadın','Kırmızı')   
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_values) = 2
```